# Set UILabel's text without memory leak?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, memory-leaks

How can I set the text of a `UILabel` without it causing a `memory leak?`

I declare my UILabel as `weak IBOutlet` and have no `strong` references to it, however, this causes a memory leak which shows in `Instrument`:

```
mylabel.text = "text"
```

**N.B.**

The label is part of a `UICollectionViewCell` and works with a `ViewModel`.

This is where I set the `UILabel's` text:

```
override var item: ViewModelItem? {
    didSet {
        guard let item = item as? ViewModel else {
            return
        }
        mylabel.text = "text"
    }
}
```

The code get's called twice because I have to `dequeue` the cell and set the content just to get the height of the cell but it should not matter how many times the code gets called considering `mylabel` is declared as `weak`.

Comment: is "mylabel" declared as property or `IBOutlet`?

Comment: It's declared as an `IBOutlet`.

Comment: I have repeated exactly the same code thousand of times and my Instrument (Leaks) has shown no indication of memory leaks. You may have too simplified your code. The text set to the UILabel is really a literal? Isn't executed in the background thread? All such things may affect. Please show enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: What's makes you think that the label is the reason of causing the memory leak? Also I think that you should provide some details, because I would assume that this case is unreproducible so easy...

Comment: @AhmadF `Instrument` shows setting the `UILabel's` text as being the memory leak. I am setting it to a string literal as in my code, and I still get a leak. When I comment out `mylabel.text = "text"` I get no leak.

Comment: All the same. I put the updated code into my custom cell with no modification. And call it thousands of times. Get no indication of Leaks. You should better think some other parts of your code might be affecting and find it.

Comment: It could be your `viewmodel` is holding your label on the heap. Did you declare it as `unowned`?